# Different yaml file(s) according to different environment (dev,test,live)

Tags: php, drupal, yaml, pantheon

I think reading different config files according to different environments is required in most of the web application, but I just don't know how to achieve this in pantheon.

For example, I have a config.yml file located in the root directory, it stores some configuration items, and those items will *vary* according to different environment, so is it possible to tell pantheon, use different copy of "config.yml" in different envs (i.e. dev/test/live).

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to keep each configuration in separate files, and load just the required, e.g.:

```
config.prod.yml
config.dev.yml
config.test.yml
```

And in script where you require file, do smth like:

```
$env = YOUR_CURRENT_ENV;
require 'config.'. $env .'.yml';
```

This YOUR_CURRENT_ENV can be set manually, or set using any other means (check IP, set php_ini in server. etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually knew I can detect pantheon envs by: if (isset($_SERVER['PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT'])), but, I still wanna know, if there a way to "override" a specific file according to different envs?

Comment: You can parse config from common file (same one for all envs) and than - from the one you need with specific overwrites.